# Return the employees who have had at least 2 distinct orders where some product on the order had quantity >= 5

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

Return the employees who have had at least 2 distinct orders where some product on the order had quantity >= 5.

```
 * Format:
 * EmployeeId, EmployeeName, orderCount
```

I have written this so far:

```
ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Employee.EmployeeId,EmployeeName, COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.EmployeeId) as orderCount "
                + "FROM Employee,Orders,OrderedProduct"
                + " WHERE quantity >=5 AND Employee.EmployeeId = Orders.EmployeeId AND Orders.OrderId = OrderedProduct.OrderId"
                + " GROUP BY OrderedProduct.OrderId,Employee.EmployeeId,EmployeeName");
```

and i get the result:

```
EmployeeId, EmployeeName, orderCount

E0002, E. Edwards, 1

E0007, I. Irvin, 1

E0006, D. Davis, 1

E0001, B. Bogart, 1

E0006, D. Davis, 1
```

But what i am looking for is

```
OrderId, EmployeeId, EmployeeName, orderCount

E0006, D. Davis, 2
```

I can't figure out how to count D. Davis twice and would REALLY appreciate some help

Comment: without knowing what your data looks like, it's harder to provide you with an answer for this

Comment: To clarify,  are you looking for two orders, where one of the orders had quantity >=5  or two orders where each order had a quantity  >=5 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's 2 orders where each order had a quantity >=5

Comment: In the result I'm getting I'm getting D.Davis twice I just don't know how to count him twice and put it as orderCount

Comment: I'll second @ChuckvanderLinden's comment (about wanting to see the data), however, my first look would be the `DISTINCT Orders.EmployeeId` which could consolidate the duplicate records for "D. Davis"

Comment: Well as I said without knowing the format and content of the source data it's hard to be sure.. but offhand, it looks like you are trying to do joins via the where clause, instead of an actual join.. that would seem like the first miss-step  (unless that's something allowed by mysql)

Comment: I just need some sort of way to count my result I'm getting at the end into my orderCount in the select statement but I'm not sure how i would do the subquery with the count function

Comment: Your question doesn't seem specific to JDBC, you might want to consider removing the JDBC specific code (and the jdbc tag) and focus on the SQL query itself.

Comment: In any case, the presence of `OrderedProduct.OrderId` in your `GROUP BY` looks really suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter  the result adding `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.EmployeeId) > 1`

```
ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Employee.EmployeeId, EmployeeName, COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.OrderId) as orderCount "
              + " FROM Employee,Orders,OrderedProduct"
              + " WHERE quantity >=5 AND Employee.EmployeeId = Orders.EmployeeId AND Orders.OrderId = OrderedProduct.OrderId"
              + " GROUP BY Employee.EmployeeId,EmployeeName"
              + " HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.OrderId) >1 ");
```

Comment: check if  E0006, D. Davis, 1 have really two order   could be that  employeeID or name is not the same  (countaing a space )  because   you have two row in your result but ithe employee is the same you should have one row with this value

Comment: ...   answer  updated  with correct column  for orderId

Answer (score 0):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  For this query, you can do:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId, e.EmployeeName, COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderId) as orderCount
FROM Employee e JOIN
     Orders o
     ON e.EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId JOIN
     OrderedProduct op
     ON o.OrderId = op.OrderId
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.EmployeeName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderId) > 1 AND MAX(quantity) >= 5;
```

You should understand how this works.  To count orders, you need to count `OrderId`s.  The condition on `quantity` has to happen *after* the `GROUP BY`.